# Auto-open NERDTree in "EVERY" tab

Tags: vim, nerdtree

Is it possible to open NERDTree in every tab with pressing <kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>T</kbd> in NERDTree, if yes, How?

Comment: How do you open it in split view? It works, but it opened the file over it when i double clicked on the file. vim newbie here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably not the best way, but if you edit plugin/NERDTree.vim and change this:

```
 exec "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ". g:NERDTreeMapOpenInTab ." :call <SID>openInNewTab(0)<cr>"
```

to this:

```
 exec "nnoremap <silent> <buffer> ". g:NERDTreeMapOpenInTab ." :call <SID>openInNewTab(0)<cr>:NERDTree<cr>"
```

it will alter the binding of 't' in the NERDTree view to first open the file and then open NERDTree. Note, that the NERDTree views will not keep in sync.

Answer (score 115):

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd BufEnter * NERDTreeMirror
```

edit: The above command seems to open the new tab in NERDTree's buffer. Instead use this as mentioned by [wejrowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/837046/wejrowski) in the comment below :

```
autocmd BufWinEnter * NERDTreeMirror
```

Comment: You add these to your ~/.vimrc

Comment: I did this and when I open a file through nerdtree in a new tab "t" it opens the file in a new tab in the side nerdtree panel and makes the main area blank. so there's no nerdtree anymore.

Comment: Hmm I fixed it by swapping "autocmd BufEnter * NERDTreeMirror" with "autocmd BufWinEnter * NERDTreeMirror".. seems like it was opening nerdTree then using that nerdtree window to open the buffer

Comment: this is the wrong answer. use nerdtreetabs. nerdtree is garbage without it

Comment: Quickfix window doesn't work properly with that.

Answer (score 65):

I wrote a vim plugin that does this and also adds some goodies on top (i.e. keeps all trees in sync, ensures meaningful tab captions - not captions like 'NERD_tree_1' etc.).

It's here on Github: https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs

Comment: this plugin seems to work really well, fixes all of these types of shortcomings in NERDTree. Good job!

Comment: used for two seconds so far, and i love it

Comment: This is the way NERDTree should work out of the box. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much for writing this dude -- super useful! It still works with the latest version of NERDTree -- hopefully it continues to work.

Answer (score 49):

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
autocmd BufEnter * NERDTreeMirror

autocmd VimEnter * wincmd w
```

This one is a little better than Dustin's one because it places the cursor directly on the file you are intending to edit for quick edits. Thanks dustin for the original example ^^

Answer (score 7):

A better solution is to open NERDTree only if there are no command line arguments set.

`" Open NERDTree in new tabs and windows if no command line args set
autocmd VimEnter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif 
autocmd BufEnter * if !argc() | NERDTreeMirror | endif`

NERDTree is e.g. not helpful if you do a `git commit` or something similiar.

Answer (score 6):

How about toggling it.

```
" in .vimrc
" NERDTree, Use F3 for toggle NERDTree
nmap <silent> <F3> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

In OSX, you just need to fn-F3 to toggle NERDTree.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was actually mentioned in [the official Repository's Readme file](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/README.markdown#faq) including three situations related to opening NERDTree automatically:

---

> How can I open a NERDTree automatically when vim starts up?

Stick this in your vimrc: `autocmd vimenter * NERDTree`

---

> How can I open a NERDTree automatically when vim starts up if no files were specified?

Stick this in your vimrc:

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
```

Note: Now start vim with plain `vim`, not `vim .`

---

> How can I open NERDTree automatically when vim starts up on opening a directory?

```
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in") | exe 'NERDTree' argv()[0] | wincmd p | ene | endif
```

This window is tab-specific, meaning it's used by all windows in the tab. This trick also prevents NERDTree from hiding when first selecting a file.