# Using gvim tabs with taglist plugin

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I've been looking at using the taglist plugin with gvim, but one of the difficulties I've been running into is that it doesn't work with gvim tabs in the way I would like. When the users starts the taglist, it only appears for the current tab; as far as I can tell, the user needs to start another taglist whenever they switch to a tab that doesn't haven't one open yet.

My question is whether or not there is some method to open a single taglist, which updates to the corresponding buffer every time the user switches to another tab, leaving the same (but updated) taglist on the side of the window.

Another possibility I've looked at was using the Mini Buffer Explorer plug-in, which largely interacts with taglist in the way I want. However, I prefer the appearance of the gvim tabs, and have generally found the gvim tabs more flexible when it comes to certain things like reordering. So with all that said, while I'm most interested in configuring how taglist works with the gvim tabs, I'm also be willing to consider other possibilities if they allow for greater flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used vim tabs for years and putting up with issues like this, then trying plugins like ctrlP and lusty, i tried switchind to buffers, read that : http://leonid.shevtsov.me/en/why-vim-tabs-are-different-from-any-other-editor, and ditched tabs in vim entirely, now things makes much more sense.

(but don't use mini buffer explorer, it's evil, lusty is way better and do the reordering automatically with most recently used)

Answer (score 0):

No. Because of how tabs are designed in Vim you can't have *real* persisting windows across tabs.

You could hack around this situation [the same way some people do with NERDTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979520/auto-open-nerdtree-in-every-tab):

```
autocmd VimEnter * TlistOpen
```

(but it's ugly) or cope with the fact that Vim is not and can't be the editor/IDE you've used for years before switching.