# How can I make NERDTree always available at left?

Tags: vim

I want to keep NERDTree always available at left *(since vim starts)*.

NERDTree documentations has nothing relating to this and I don't think it has such inbuilt feature.

Well I tried setting by my own and did this:

```
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
```

But this seems buggy, the annoying things I found are:

1. At startup the cursor is focused at NERDTree, it should be at editor window instead.
2. When closing *(with `:q`)* the editor window closes, but the NERDTree is focused *(I want to quit immediately, no wait!)*

Do you have any better idea than this?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979520/auto-open-nerdtree-in-every-tab. Your problem 1 had been solved there.

Comment: Yes, stop trying to turn Vim into an IDE: it's a hopeless endeavour.

Answer (score 0):

For 1., add an instruction to go back to the previous window:

```
autocmd VimEnter * execute 'NERDTree' | wincmd p
```

For 2., you could just use `:qa`; to automate that, you have to define an autocmd that checks whether the last remaining window is from NERDTree, something like this (untested):

```
autocmd WinEnter * if winnr('$') == 1 && exists("t:NERDTreeBufName") && bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) == 1 | quit | endif
```

Comment: It has become as hard as rock. No effect of mouse or keyboard.