# Settingup nerdTree in Vim

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I'm trying to install nerdTree for my vim editor. So far I was able to download the source from the [github](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree) in to `.vim/bundle`.

However in the [following video](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/vim-essential-plugin-nerdtree/) , they install the nerdTree via the `rake` command, but in the latest git repo does not have a rake file.

And I tried as per the new README file, to copy and the plugin to .vim/bundle. Now it works, But when I select a node, it opens up in full screen closing the nerdTree.

As per in [faq](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree#faq) I added the following line in my ~/.vimrc file but no luck.

```
autocmd vimenter * if !argc() | NERDTree | endif
```

How can I set up nerdTree and when I open a directory I want to directory structure always in the left hand side of the screen. (like in textmate)

Comment: Do you have pathogen installed? If not, you could try adding something like `runtime bundle/nerdtree/autoload/autoload.vim` to your .vimrc or copy the entire nerdtree folderstructure to the vim73 folder.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, thanks for the reply, No I havent installed pathoge (but I will not), runtime bundle/nerdtree/autoload/autoload.vim options didnt work :(

Comment: Pathogen takes care of finding and sourcing the appropriate files in folders outside of the "normal" folder structure. I honestly have no idea how to do that yourself but you could take a look at the pathogen script to get some pointers on how it's done. The easiest short-term solution though is to simply copy the entire tree's subfolders *(autoload, nerdtree_plugin/plugin/syntax & doc)* to `$VIMRUNTIME`. At least, after that you know it's working *(or not)*

Comment: The plugin seems to be installed; the issue is that selecting a node usually does not close the NERDTree window. How do you select (`<Enter>`?), and do you have any other plugins / autocmds that could interfere?

Comment: @IngoKarkat, thanks for the reply, No, I'm using <enter>, to select.

Comment: I finally it working with the help of following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979520/auto-open-nerdtree-in-every-tab/7640505#7640505

Answer (score 1):

[NERDTree documentation](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt)

It looks like the `NERDTreeQuitOnOpen` option might be on. Try putting this in your vimrc:

```
let NERDTreeQuitOnOpen=0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, finally I got it working with the help of following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979520/auto-open-nerdtree-in-every-tab/7640505#7640505