# How to keep NERDTree open while opening a new tab?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

When I type ":tabe" to open a new tab,the NERDTree will hide?How to keep it open in the new tab?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-open NERDTree in "EVERY" tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979520/auto-open-nerdtree-in-every-tab)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [nerdtree-tabs](https://github.com/jistr/vim-nerdtree-tabs) instead of nerdtree (which is not tab-aware).

Comment: Not maintain anymore.